# Any way to hide dynamic parameter's value from the log file

Tags: security, cruisecontrol.net

We are trying to create a ccnet project to automate the deployment in the production environment as we already do with test, integration and acceptance environments.  Of course, we don't want to store the username and password of the user with the required rights on production servers in the ccnet.config file.  The idea is to ask this password from the user forcing the project.  Dynamic parameters are ok for that except that :

- Text parameters don't have a pasword option to hide characters.
- Parameters values are stored in the log file

We can live with the first problem but of course not with the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another option. You can give the account running the CCNET service permissions to access and write to the production environment. Just make sure that the account doesn't have interactive log in permissions to handle security concerns.

Comment: I was indeed thinking of that solution as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [CruiseControl.net svn repository](http://ccnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ccnet/trunk/project/Remote/Parameters/) -  this behaviour is not implemented currently. You can file an feature request through [Jira](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET) - or, better yet, if you have the skills - create an improvement with a patch. This should be relatively easy to write, the code is well documented.